# FreeRTOS Queues

Tags: queue, esp32, freertos, rtos

I am new to FreeRTOS and learning queues at the moment.
I have a Task_3 who send 5 integers to the queue and Task 4 who reads the queue and prints the values read. Problem is that i write  0..4 to the queue but the Task 4 reads on all 5 positions of the queue the value 5. Why not 0..4 ?

The send task 3

```
    void task_3(void *args)
    {
        uint32_t count = 0;
        uint32_t *Value;
    
        Value = &count;
        ESP_EARLY_LOGI(TAG, "Task 3 entered..");
    
        
        if (myQueue_2 == NULL)
        {
            printf("myQueue_2 could not be created !\n");
        }
        
        ESP_EARLY_LOGI("TASK 3", "Data waiting in myQueue_2_1 : %d, Space available : %d", uxQueueMessagesWaiting(myQueue_2), uxQueueSpacesAvailable(myQueue_2));
       
        for (count = 0; count < 5;count++)
        {
            ESP_EARLY_LOGI("TASK 3", "Value = %d\n", *Value);
            xQueueSend(myQueue_2, (void*)&Value, (TickType_t)0);
        }
    
        ESP_EARLY_LOGI("TASK 3", "Data waiting in myQueue_2_1 : %d, Space available : %d", 
        uxQueueMessagesWaiting(myQueue_2), uxQueueSpacesAvailable(myQueue_2));
        while (1)
        {
            vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(500));
        }
    }
```

Output of Task 3

```
I (0) TASK 3: Data waiting in myQueue_2_1 : 0, Space available : 5
I (10) TASK 3: Value = 0
I (10) TASK 3: Value = 1
I (20) TASK 3: Value = 2
I (20) TASK 3: Value = 3
I (20) TASK 3: Value = 4
```

The read task 4

```
    void task_4(void *args)
    {
        uint32_t *RxValue = NULL;
    
        while (1)
        {
            vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(500));
            
            if (uxQueueMessagesWaiting(myQueue_2) > 0)
            {
                xQueueReceive(myQueue_2, &RxValue, (TickType_t)5);
                ESP_EARLY_LOGI("TASK 4", "Received from myQueue_2 = %d\n", *RxValue);
                ESP_EARLY_LOGI("TASK 4", "Data waiting in myQueue_2 : %d, Space available : %d", 
                uxQueueMessagesWaiting(myQueue_2), uxQueueSpacesAvailable(myQueue_2));
            }
        }
    }
```

Output of task 4

```
I (30) TASK 3: Data waiting in myQueue_2_1 : 5, Space available : 0
I (1300) TASK 4: Received from myQueue_2 = 5
I (1300) TASK 4: Data waiting in myQueue_2 : 4, Space available : 1
I (1800) TASK 4: Received from myQueue_2 = 5
I (1800) TASK 4: Data waiting in myQueue_2 : 3, Space available : 2
I (2300) TASK 4: Received from myQueue_2 = 5
I (2300) TASK 4: Data waiting in myQueue_2 : 2, Space available : 3
I (2800) TASK 4: Received from myQueue_2 = 5
I (2800) TASK 4: Data waiting in myQueue_2 : 1, Space available : 4
I (3300) TASK 4: Received from myQueue_2 = 5
I (3300) TASK 4: Data waiting in myQueue_2 : 0, Space available : 5
```

Comment: Your are putting (the same) integer pointer into the queue and read it back. You should send the integers by value e.g. xQueueSend(myQueue_2, (void*)&count, (TickType_t)0); and receive it into an integer variable uint32_t RxValue;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xQueueSend()` sends a pointer to a value, not the value itself. It doesn't make a copy of what's being pointed to. If the value that's pointed to changes before the queue is read, the reader will see the new value.

Your code enqueues the same five pointers to the variable `count`, not five copies of the value of `count`. By the time `task_4` runs, `count` is equal to 5. So `task_4` reads 5 each time.

The correct way to do this is to pass a different pointer each time. You might `malloc()` the value each time and free it:

```
for (count = 0; count < 5;count++)
    {
        uint32_t *value = (uint32_t *)malloc(sizeof(uint32_t));

        if (value) {
            *value = count;
            ESP_EARLY_LOGI("TASK 3", "Value = %d\n", *value);
            xQueueSend(myQueue_2, (void*)&Value, (TickType_t)0);
        } else {
            ESP_EARLY_LOGI("TASK 3", "malloc failed");
        }
    }
```

and

```
while (1)
    {
        vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(500));
        
        if (uxQueueMessagesWaiting(myQueue_2) > 0)
        {
            xQueueReceive(myQueue_2, &RxValue, (TickType_t)5);
            ESP_EARLY_LOGI("TASK 4", "Received from myQueue_2 = %d\n", *RxValue);
            ESP_EARLY_LOGI("TASK 4", "Data waiting in myQueue_2 : %d, Space available : %d", 
            uxQueueMessagesWaiting(myQueue_2), uxQueueSpacesAvailable(myQueue_2));
            free(RxValue);
        }
    }
```

The first code fragment allocates storage and enqueues it each time, so each item queued will be different. It's extremely important that the second code fragment free the storage, otherwise the program will leak memory and eventually run out of it.

Since a pointer is large enough to store `uint32_t`, you could also just cast the counter to be `void *` and cast it back to `uint32_t` in the receiving task. If you want to pass anything larger than a pointer you'll need to `malloc()` it and initialize it or do your own memory management of the objects you want to pass.

Answer (score 2):

Just a follow up on romkey's answer as whilst it does work, I feel it could be a bit misleading.

xQueueSend() does actually copy and send values, not just pointers. It's just that in your example the value passed to xQueueSend() is itself a pointer (&Value, rather than just Value).

There's no need to allocate fresh memory or do any casting to and from pointers here. You can just pass by value as I believe HS2 was suggesting in their comment.
Hopefully the modified code below can explain what I mean:

```
for (count = 0; count < 5;count++)
{ 
    ESP_EARLY_LOGI("TASK 3", "Value = %d\n", count);
    xQueueSend(myQueue_2, (void*) &count, (TickType_t)0);
}
```

And

```
while (1)
{
    vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(500));
    
    if (uxQueueMessagesWaiting(myQueue_2) > 0)
    {
        xQueueReceive(myQueue_2, &RxValue, (TickType_t)5);
        ESP_EARLY_LOGI("TASK 4", "Received from myQueue_2 = %d\n", RxValue);
        ESP_EARLY_LOGI("TASK 4", "Data waiting in myQueue_2 : %d, Space available : %d", 
        uxQueueMessagesWaiting(myQueue_2), uxQueueSpacesAvailable(myQueue_2));
    }
}
```

What's happening here is you pass a pointer (&count) to xQueueSend, it copies the value of count, not the address &count into the queue.
You then give xQueueReceive a pointer to the location where you want the value copied out of the queue, &RxValue. xQueueReceive copies the value into the location pointed to by &RxValue, RxValue.

It's very much possible to send larger types than pointers without manually allocating and freeing memory, provided they are of known size.

How much memory xQueueSend copies into the queue is determined when the queue is created, it's the second argument to xQueueCreate.

Allocating and sending pointers instead may become worthwhile if you wish to send very large structures as it avoids the work of copying everything in and out, but for a few integers there's no real benefit.